# Storing data to Flash in Wireless Sensor Networks on loosing connection

Tags: embedded, filesystems

I have to implement an optimal solution to store values of sensor into NOR Flash with time stamps on loosing connection and send to the central server when connection comes back. A queue like implementation is needed. Will anyone please suggest an implementation Open source or proprietary, or any algorithms for same. It should have properties like wear leveling, write fail safe and erase fail safe.

It is a 256Mb Spansion NOR flash(S25FL256S). I need to store only less than 64bytes (including time stamp) every 60 seconds, if there is no connection. Page size of flash is 256 bytes and sector size is 256KB. Erase cycle endurance of flash is 100,000

Comment: A sensible answer would require answers to the following questions: How much NOR flash do you have available? What is the page/erase block size? What is the size of the data record you need to store?  How frequently are you storing records? What is the erase cycle endurance of the flash memory?  Anyone attempting to answer without this information is kidding themselves (and you).  I have done exactly this previously, and all the above were critical to an appropriate solution.

Comment: It is a **256Mb** Spansion NOR flash(S25FL256S). I need to store only less than **64bytes** (including time stamp) every **60 seconds**, if there is no connection. Page size of flash is 256 bytes and sector size is 256KB. Erase cycle endurance of flash is 100,000

Comment: The appropriate response to comments on deficiencies in the question is to edit the question rather than add a comment with information pertinent to the question.  The question has to stand-alone in the absence of any comments - which may not get read.  The 64 bytes includes the timestamp or not?

Comment: Given your low data rate and small record size, why do you have such a large flash memory with enormous sector size?  You have enough memory to store nearly eight years of data - is wear-levelling really an issue, or is this memory used for other purposes as well.  Remember I asked how much flash was *available* not how large the part was.  How much can you afford to allocate to this task?

Comment: Another question - how long a connection outage should the system be able to survive without data loss?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, now I edit the question with additional information. Regarding the large memory, the hardware is designed as a general platform along with add-on cards, for many similar applications, not particular for this application. The flash memory can be used mostly for this purpose, only some configuration data are stored in flash(about 2KB). The connection outage might be of some mins, to some days. but it happens too frequent(may be  lost many times within a short period). We can allocate only 1 or 2 KB for this task.

Comment: Any solution would require at least one sector, simply because data erasure is per sector. The chip has an alternate mode that supports 32 4kb sectors.  That would be more efficient.

Comment: Sounds like this data is somewhat mission-critical, so you probably should use some sort of error detection like CRC or ECC flash.

Comment: @Clifford: Actually I'm using lower 32 4KB sectors for storing configuration data. Now I implemented a queue implementation so that I can enqueue and dequeue data from flash, and flash write can be extended all over the flash.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks. In the current implementation I avoided ECC or CRC, but need to have implement that on later releases.

Comment: @123rgt : So now your requirements conflict with your hardware capability.  The solution I have in mind will require two sectors at least so you will need to commit 512kb, not the 1 or 2kb you have suggested.

Comment: ... and also you have suggested allocating ny 2Kb of flash, but want to store several days of data at 64 bytes per minute.  How is that going to work!?

Comment: Some of your requirements remain *only* in the comments.  You should use the comments to improve the question rather then including information relevant to the question in comments.  Doing that will help you see how your requirements conflict; something that you may need to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use *N* flash sectors where *N* > 1.  Ideally the sectors will be of equal size, and smaller sectors are more efficient if only a small amount of data storage is needed.  The sectors start blank (all 0xFF).  Each record is ideally a factor of the total sector size (so 64 or 128 bytes might be good choices.  Each record comprises:

```
<timestamp><data><integrity check>
```

Each record is written sequentially and contiguously to the flash memory, but critically the `<integrity check>` is written *last*. The `<integrity check>` may be a CRC or simply the one's complement of the `<timestamp>` for example.  I suggest a Unix Epoch timestamp of type time_t as it is simple and universal.  Writing the `<integrity check>` last allows the detection of incomplete records (due to power fail during write for example).

As each sector boundary is crossed the next sector is erased, wrapping from sector *N*-1 to 0, so you will always have at least *N*-1 sectors worth of data and up to *N* sectors worth.  (this is why a larger number of small sectors is better then a small number of large sectors).  This circular buffer of flash pages provides wear-levelling.  For example given 2 * 256k sectors and 64 byte records written once per minute, each page will be erased every 2.844 days, so for an endurance of 100000 erase/write cycles, the flash will endure 779 years.  This is overkill, but this uses the minimum number of sectors that happen to be rather large, you need to calculate the endurance for any specific combination of *N* and sector size:

```
(((*N* - 1) * sector_size) / record_size) * write_period * flash_endurance
```

For example 2 x 4Kb sectors with 64 byte records written every minute would last only 12 years.

Initialisation of start-up requires scanning the flash reading the timestamps to find the highest numbered timestamp that is not 0xffffffff (or 0xffffffffffffffff for 64 bit time_t), and which passes the integrity check, so that to know where to write the next record (immediately after this "most recent" record.  Note if you really want to run for 779 years - or even past Jan 19 2038, then you *will* need a 64 bit timestamp, but for most purposes you'll get away with 32 - at least for the product warranty period!).

A 2 * 256kb sector implementation guarantees at least 256kb of history data will be available, for 64 byte records, that a little more than 68 hours.  If only 2 4kb sectors were used, the minimum history reduced to 64 minutes.  You could log only when the connection is lost, but it may be better to log continuously and then have the remote client request missing data by start/end timestamp whenever it needs it.  This approach will allow data to be retrieved even when it is "lost" for reasons other then connection loss detectable by your system, and it could allow multiple clients to be connected that may independently loose connection and need to recover data independently.